# Search for a list of strings in ansible register variable

Tags: ansible

I am newbie to ansible. I have a task where in I have to register the output of a first task and execute second task when some list of variables are present in the output of first task. It looks like below

```
- name: execute first task
 command: /tmp/somescript.sh
 register: output
 - fail:
 msg: when {{ item }} present in. output.stdout or output.stdlines
 with_items:
        - a
        - b
        - c
```

Comment: check the `fail` module documentation on how to structure it.

Comment: I did search for it in ansible documentation . I can only find example which shows how to achieve it with one variable not list of variables

Comment: the only example in the module's page contains a `when` clause, not `if` as you used.

Comment: I did that but didn't find a solution exactly. It only contains example for one variable not list of variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't test the output yet as you posted on your code. 
It should be something like this:

```
 - fail:
     msg: 'Fail looking for {{ item }} in output'
   when: item not in output.stdout or item not in output.stdlines
   with_items:
        - a
        - b
        - c
```

As @ilias-sp said, take a look here: [https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fail_module.html](http://Fail%20Module%20-%20Ansible)

Comment: I Will try to do that as suggested.  Keep you posted

Comment: Thanks a lot bro. Its working for me. The only thing I changed  in your code is getting rid of {" in when condition as ansible doesn't support in jinja format in when condition. The code is perfectly working fine for me.